# Print diffrent type files with lpr at once

Tags: printing, printers, thermal-printer, receipt, lpr

I want to print different files using lpr command to a thermal printer. They need to be printed at once because they're from the same receipt. If I use the following commands

`lpr -P POS58 aux.txt`

`lpr -P POS58 qr.bin`

They are printed fine but there's too much time in between the first and second printing. But if I do it like this

`lpr -P POS58 aux.txt qr.bin`

Only the first file is printed, it doesn't happen with same extension files but it happens here. How could I print all at once?

Comment: Isn't the end of `aux.txt` the code to start printing such as line feed?

Comment: `aux.txt` is just normal text ending with `NULL`. But it happens the same the other way, the QR is printed but it doesn't print the next file

Comment: Please try adding the line feed code to the end of the aux.txt file and then concatenating aux.txt and qr.bin as binary data before sending.